# FineTuning a LLM for generating Algolia Search query

Tags: deep-learning, large-language-model

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h4jam.png)
I'm currently working on a project where I need to fine-tune a Large Language Model (LLM) on an Algolia search query dataset. Despite numerous attempts, I haven't been able to achieve satisfactory results.

Sample dataset:
Here are 2 columns first one is User prompt and second one is Generated response by chatbot

How i do this task, Please help me